# How to change form of Bootstrap dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I want to make dropdown look like this:

[image]

and now is by default, look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/naapy.png

Here is html code:

```
     <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-togle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <b>Download</b>
          <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
```

**EDITED - example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gnEAe/2/

I think, I should overwrite somehing in dropdown.js or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have edited jsfiddle...

first add class test where

`<div class="navbar test">`

also you need to add css like this....

```
.test .dropdown-menu:after, .test .dropdown-menu:before {
    border:0 !important;
}

.test .dropdown-menu {
    left:-13px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top:none !important;
}
```

this will give you basic idea of what i am talking...
http://jsfiddle.net/gnEAe/3/

Comment: How to include Bootstrap in jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to overwrite something in your javascript. But you should write some css to style your list.

here is a tutorial to style list :

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/